# Homotopy Methods: Show there is no path connecting roots

Tags: numerical-methods

This is a question from Cheney and Kincaid's *Numerical Analysis* (3rd ed, pg 138).

Consider the homotopy $h(t,x)=tf(X)+(1-t)g(x)$, in which $f(x)=x^2-5x+6$ and $g(x)=x^2-1$. Show that there is no path connecting a root of $g$ to a root of $f$.

I'm a bit confused, since clearly you can create a homotopy between them. The chapter text does not provide any insight. Are there other requirements to connect the roots besides there being a homotopy?

Comment: I think that you should clarify what do they exactly mean by the "path connecting root". It's clear that there is a homotopy, but it's possible that somewhere in between you have a polynomial with no real roots. And that's an obstruction for path existence.

Comment: @Evgeny, Oh, so if I can find a t such that h(t, x) does not have roots (and thus I can't find a solution at that t), then a path doesn't exist?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I've meant :)